# Pass variable to a javascript from php view file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am developing a web application where you can delete users. I am using codeigniter framework to develop this. 
Using this code, I am invoking "Doconfirm()" function in external javascript file.

```
      //my view file
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Assests/Images/cross.png" alt="Delete User"  title="Delete User" onClick="return Doconfirm()();" >

      //inside DoConfirm function javascript file
      window.location =  site_url +"user/deleteusers/id";
```

I want to pass id from the view to javascript doconfirm function. I know I can take the id using this php code.

```
      <?php echo $row['id']; ?>
```

What I want is to pass the id to the external javascript function "Doconfirm()" from the view. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the id as a parameter in your onClick:

```
  //my view file
  <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Assests/Images/cross.png" 
       alt="Delete User"  title="Delete User" 
       onClick="return Doconfirm(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>);" >

  //inside DoConfirm function javascript file
  function doConfirm(id) {
      window.location =  site_url +"user/deleteusers/" + id;
  }
```